# How to customise web service response xml

Tags: java, jax-ws, websphere-8

I am trying to migrate a web service from IIS to Websphere. I have created a Java class containing the services as well as the necessary supporting classes. I have used exactly the same names in Java as were used in C#.

The web service is then generated from the service class using a wizard. `JAX-WS` and `Document/Wrapped` are selected. However, the service response differs from the original.

Original:

```
<StaffAttendingResponse xmlns="http://acme.com/">
    <StaffAttendingResult>
        <StaffAttendance>
            <Guid>edffd67b-c7dc-4fe6-bc3c-846bf04e4ac6</Guid>
            <Name>Wonka</Name>
            <Vorname>Willy</Vorname>
            ...
```

Websphere:

```
<StaffAttendingResponse xmlns="http://acme.com/">
    <return>
        <guid>edffd67b-c7dc-4fe6-bc3c-846bf04e4ac6</guid>
        <name>Wonka</name>
        <vorname>Willy</vorname>
        ...
```

The response is a list of `StaffAttendance` objects. The Java version is missing the `StaffAttendingResult` node, the `StaffAttendance` nodes are called `return` and the object attributes are all lowercase.

I have tried using the `Document/Bare` option but `wsgen` throws an exception and does not complete the generation.

Comment: If you want to create exactly the same service, try to export wsdl from you C# application, and then generate stub classes in Java using that WSDL, instead of writing your own. You can change the `return` tag using `@WebResult` annotation.

Comment: @Gas - thanks - I have tried exporting the WSDL but Websphere cannot import it -> Exception. I suspect my installation is corrupt - so many problems :-(